# Counting Items from Comma Delimited Tuple

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` that has data as follows:

```
var intents = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("60b0e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a21f1c0f1",
        "Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ," +
        "Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4",
        "RescheudleApt ,RescheudleApt ,ConfirmApt ,ConfirmApt ," + 
        "RescheudleApt ,RescheudleApt"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("re80e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a54f1c0f1", "ConfirmAppt"),
};
```

The desired output for would be something like this:

```
60b0e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a21f1c0f1
Options: 13

d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4
RescheudleApt : 3
ConfirmApt: 2
```

Since this is a Tuple the items are seperated into "Item 1" and "Item 2" meaning that `60b0e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a21f1c0f1` and `Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options ,Options` are different properties.

I have gotten as far as this:

```
        foreach (var item in intents)
        {
            var intentList = item.Item2.Split(',')
                .Select(x => x.Trim())
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .ToList().GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
        }
```

Which only gives me the output of two properties:

```
Value : Options
Count : 13
```

EDIT:
**Intents** is a `List<Tuple<string, string>>()`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is internets? Is it the list of tuples?

Comment: Yes, I should have added that. Editing now.

Comment: don't have a vs here, but my answer should to the job. just add a level of nesting and unwrap at the end :)

Comment: @Jaster You can always use http://dotnetfiddle.net ;)

Comment: wow, didn't knew that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
intents.Select(root => new 
{ 
    Key = root.Item1, 
    Values = root.Item2.Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(g => new 
        { 
            Value = g.Key, 
            Count = g.Count() 
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
})
.ToList()
.ForEach(x => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
    x.Values.ForEach(child => Console.WriteLine($"{child.Key}: {child.Value}"))
});
```

Comment: Also can you explain to me why you do `.ToList()` before doing another `GroupBy`? Isn't that unnecessary?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only thing I have noticed is that .ForEach seems to be an extension method only for List. This LINQ stuff is a bit difficult for me to wrap my head around. I'm passing this up to the frontend from an API. What do you think the best format for that would be ?

Comment: @Frank I think Jaster intended to show that after the last `ToList()` you have the list you want. What they did afterwards is just print it out (like you did in your question) but you should be able to do anything you want with that list from there on. Passing stuff from APIs is usually done with JSON if you mean that. JSON also has a lot of supported stuff in C#.

Comment: I would go with specific classes rather than annonymus stuff. So instead of new {..} you go new MyApiResultClass{...}

Comment: btw, you don't have to use linq, just use regular synhax with loops, etc. The optimizer will do the rest. (unless its LINQ2SQL or something like that)

Comment: @Joelius the inner ToList is not needed. True :)

Comment: Now you're confusing me.. do you mean the ToList? Or what's the _inner_ ForEach?

Comment: Ahh okay. I added an Edit to remove it from the answer as well if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to select the items into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`, where the `Key` is `Item1`, and the `Value` is *another* dictionary that has the unique items in `Item2` for `Keys`, and the `Values` is the count of each item, instead of using anonymous types.

Note that you can add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to the `Split` method, which allows us to remove the check for `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))`, and there's no need to call `.ToList()` before doing the `GroupBy`.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> results = intents.ToDictionary(
    item => item.Item1,
    item => item.Item2.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count()));
```

Now we can iterate through the results like this:

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + Environment.NewLine +
        string.Join(Environment.NewLine, item.Value.Select(v => $" - {v.Key}: {v.Value}")) +
        Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And the output looks like:

[image: ![enter image description here]